# RC low pass filter for NTC

Tags: filter, low-pass, thevenin, thermistor, time-constant

I want to measure temperature using an NTC resistor and ADC (of an MCU). A low pass input filter is required with a certain cutoff frequency. Here is the recommended schematic:

[image]

So I replace everything left of \$C_1\$ with a Thevenin voltage source with internal resistance of 5 kΩ (at room temperature). And then I get a filter time constant of 5 kΩ * 100 nF = 0.5 ms.

**But what is this filter actually filtering?**

Voltage at the point between \$R_1\$ and \$R_\text{NTC}\$ is input to my filter and ADC node is the output... And they are shorted/share the same wire! So there shouldn't be any voltage difference between these two points.
So what am I filtering if not the voltage on \$R_\text{NTC}\$?

Comment: From where does the requirement of the low pass filter comes from in the first place?

Comment: That capacitor filters out the quick variations of the voltage you see on the point named ADC. Of course all the wire has the same voltage but if it tries to change fast, the capacitor eats it.

Comment: @Justme An anti-aliasing filter (perhaps) ?

Comment: @Unimportant We can only guess, that is why I asked. To be honest, what is the expected bandwidth of temperature measurement and would it matter if it had no AA filter at any sampling rate?

Comment: @justme The requirement comes from customer. They want to have a low pass filter here. But that is not the question here. Rather, the question is about analysis of the circuit given in the picture.

Comment: The schematic in the picture does not show why the capacitor is there and what it would filter, it's just an RC filter for ADC input to reduce bandwidth of voltage signal. In real life there could be 10 meters of wiring gathering noise from nearby radio mast or noisy Vcc power supply. Or the ADC needs low AC impedance. Without knowing anything else about the system the cap is useless.

Comment: If there is a filter, it is "dependent" of R_NTC ...

Comment: @Antonio51 As stated in question, we can assume room temperature and thus nominal resistance. The question is if there is a low pass filter here and if so, what it filters.
-Justme There aren't long cables or any extraordinary stuff, just a short trace on the PCB between the MCU and these 3 components in the picture.

Comment: The capacitor is not going to hurt your DC measurement - the temperature & so the thermistor's resistance change slowly wrt time (probably).  This is probably a belts-and-suspenders sort of recommendation, especially considering someone told you to "do it this way".

Comment: If your customer asks a capacitor and you don't understand why, we also don't know why they want it, so ask them. They might have a good reason, or a bad reason, so the capacitor may not be required at all. We don't know which MCU and ADC type there is, but for some MCUs 5k source impedance might be too high so capacitor makes it much lower.

Comment: And that's the problem with questions like this.  The OP wants an answer or advice, but we don't have enough information to give a definitive answer.  What's the input characteristics of the ADC in the MCU is one piece of missing information.

Comment: It is clear that an NTC generates noise (it is a resistor, of course ... but not "metallic" or carbon ... and therefore "noise" even more "erratic"). Ok. It's fine to take care of its "noise", but what about the "uncertainty" of the measurement by the ADC ... if its "noisy" "reference" is the supply voltage of the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parallel capacitor does indeed provide some filtering of the output voltage. This is because the voltage across \$R_{NTC}\$ is dependent on the impedance \$Z_{eq}= \frac{R_{NTC} \cdot Z_C}{R_{NTC} + Z_C} \$ and this impedance is frequency dependent.

Have a look at the frequency response: -

[image]

Clearly, this is a frequency response of a lowpass filter. In your circuit you are only dealing with a DC voltage (the supply \$V_{CC}\$) so I don't see the advantage of including a capacitor here.

However, if there for some reason are **ripples** (small ac components) or noise present the lowpass filter will help remove those unwanted signals. Below I have made 3 simulations

1. With no noise or ac-components. Here the capacitor does nothing.
2. With a 10kHz sinusoid added to VCC to "act" as noise and the capacitor removed. Here the output is practically useless for temperature measurements.
3. With a 10kHz sinusoid added to VCC to "act" as noise and the capacitor reinstated. Here the capacitor somewhat removes the oscillations, though some ripples are still present.

[image]

I want to emphasize that the 2nd and 3rd simulation are only useful for the sake of explanation and cannot be used to simulate the output of the system with actual noise present. This is because noise by definition is stochastic, while a sinusoid is obviously a deterministic signal.

---

After a discussion with Justme in the comments I looked in the datasheet for the MCU used in an Arduino, [ATmega48A](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf) and on page 253 they mention something that you might find useful: -

[image]

Comment: Since it goes to an ADC it might take a high frequency sample of the DC voltage, which means the capacitor might be required to keep the AC impedance low enough. It depends on MCU and the ADC type.

Comment: @Justme I'm not an expert on this, I just wrote what I know. But for this simple circuit is it really necessary to use a high sampling frequency? To me, a high sampling frequency would indicate you were interested in sudden changes of the temperature, for which this simple NTC-thermometer circuit would not be a good choice.

Comment: This is not about high sampling rate. If the resistors were too large for the ADC input, for example 1 Mohm, you would not be able to read the voltage correctly even if you tried to read once per hour, because voltage sampling time for a sample/hold ADC is too fast.

Comment: @Justme I'm out of my depth here. If you could write an answer where you elaborated on this and why and how a resistance can be too large for the ADC input I would be very interested.

Comment: Every MCU has a section what kind of signals work well with the ADC input and why. While an interesting subject, it would not be an answer for this question so I am not going to write one. If you make a new question about it I can try to answer but first check that such a question is not already asked and answered.

Comment: @Carl The way understood your answer is that there is a low pass filter for supply voltage. It stops supply noise from reaching ADC. There is no Low pass filter between voltage on NTC and ADC that would do "averaging" of the measured voltage. Is this correct?

Comment: @VeliborSimovic I'm not sure what you mean by "averaging the measured voltage" but the rest of what you are saying is true.